# Initialise a structure of arrays of pointers to const strings

Tags: c, gcc

I am looking for a data structure in C that allows me to declare and initialise hundreds of strings with a compressed syntax, such as that below, is this possible in C11?

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {ENGLISH, SPANISH, FRENCH, NUM_LANGUAGES};

struct language_string =
{
    const char* language_hello[NUM_LANGUAGES]   = {"Hello",     "Hola",     "Bonjour"};
    const char* language_goodbye[NUM_LANGUAGES] = {"Goodbye",   "Adiós",    "Au revoir"};
};

void foo(void)
{
    printf(language_string.language_hello[ENGLISH]);        // print "Hello"
}
```

EDIT:
I have come to realise that in a header file I can expose all the strings without wrapping them in a structure or externing them, and achieve the main intent, a single line per string:

```
const char*  language_hello[NUM_LANGUAGES]   = {"Hello",   "Hola",  "Bonjour"};
const char*  language_goodbye[NUM_LANGUAGES] = {"Goodbye", "Adiós", "Au revoir"};
```

Comment: Did you even try those array initializers? They should work -- though `struct language_string = { ... }` is wrong.

Comment: As you seem to plan a multi-lingual application you might like to take a look here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is already almost right.  You can't interleave the declaration and initialization like that, though.  Here's a corrected example:

```
struct
{
    const char* language_hello[NUM_LANGUAGES];
    const char* language_goodbye[NUM_LANGUAGES]; 
} language_string = {
    {"Hello",     "Hola",     "Bonjour"},
    {"Goodbye",   "Adiós",    "Au revoir"}
};
```

Comment: Using `.language_hello = { "Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour" },` might also be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, interleaving the declaration and initialization was the main intent, thanks for confirming that it is not possible!

Comment: caf, yes as the list gets longer the designated initializer method reduces risks of stuff ups.

Answer (score 0):

For easier code maintenance, I would recommend using a syntax similar to the following:

```
#define NUM_LANGUAGES 3

typedef struct
{
    const char* hello[NUM_LANGUAGES];
    const char* goodbye[NUM_LANGUAGES];
} language_t;


const char* STR_HELLO [NUM_LANGUAGES] =
{
  "Hello",
  "Hola",
  "Bonjour"
};

const char* STR_GOODBYE [NUM_LANGUAGES] =
{
  "Goodbye",
  "Adiós",
  "Au revoir"
};


int main()
{
  language_t lang =
  {
    { STR_HELLO[0],   STR_HELLO[1],   STR_HELLO[2]   },
    { STR_GOODBYE[0], STR_GOODBYE[1], STR_GOODBYE[2] }
  };
}
```

Comment: In what way is that easier for maintenance?  Now you have to keep two (well, 3) lists in sync!